# Previously declared variable not found in loop

Tags: c, declaration, unused-variables

I am working on the implementation of a sha1 cracker as a university project.
I am trying different values with a loop for their hash value.

```
for(int a=0; a<26; a++)
{
    for(int b=0; b<26; b++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<26; c++)
        {
            for(int d=0; d<26; d++)
            {
                for(int e=0; e<26; e++)
                {

                    for(int f=0; f<26; f++)
                    {
                        result[0]=alphabet[a];
                        result[1]=alphabet[b];
                        result[2]=alphabet[c];
                        result[3]=alphabet[d];
                        result[4]=alphabet[e];
                        result[5]=alphabet[f];


                        //printf("result : %s\n candidate %x %x %x %x %x",result,candidate.a,candidate.b,candidate.c,candidate.d,candidate.e);

                        // Declarations
                        uint32_t a,b,c,d,e,temp;
                        uint32_t w[80]= {0};
                        a=h0;
                        b=h1;
                        c=h2;
                        d=h3;
                        e=h4;
```

The code underneath is just ongoing SHA-1 code.
The loops on the outside are built to test for a 6 character word every option.

If i now try to move the `uint32_t` Declaration line before the first for loop ( but still within the same function, the C compiler warns me the variables are unused and the program crashes as those variables seem to be lost within the loop. But for performance reasons, i do not want to declare them everytime new.
If i try to global declare them, the same issue happens. But when they are declared within the last loop, everything works fine

Comment: Your loop control variables are `a` .. `f` (defined in the loops like `for (int i = 0; …)`); why are you redefining them all in an inner context?  Or when you move the inner declarations outside the loops, you are hiding those variables in the inner loops and the outermost declarations are all unused.

Comment: You are declaring the variables twice.  Each `for(int x` declares the variable.  You should be able to move the `uint32_t a,b,c ...` out of the loop and before the first `for` AND you need to remove the `int` from each `for` statement.

Comment: Well, i will cleanup this later @JonathanLeffler . michael walz : This is a typo in my description, in the code they are declared right.

Comment: Get it clean before you start compiling.  You need to rethink what you are trying to do.  And use functions.  The 6 nested loops are a nightmare, but you should put the body of the inner-most loop into a function, especially if there are any more loops inside it.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn i read your answer wrong. That was the solution after i changed the names of the loop variables. If you write this as an answer, i will mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring the variables twice. Each `for(int x` declares the variable. You should be able to move the `uint32_t a,b,c ...` out of the loop and before the first `for` AND you need to remove the `int` from each for statement.

This should compile (I don't know if the code will work or do what you want it to do, as you appear to be resetting the loop variables inside the inner most loop):

```
uint32_t a,b,c,d,e,temp;
uint32_t w[80]= {0};

for(a=0; a<26; a++)
{
    for(b=0; b<26; b++)
    {
        for(c=0; c<26; c++)
        {
            for(d=0; d<26; d++)
            {
                for(e=0; e<26; e++)
                {

                    for(f=0; f<26; f++)
                    {
                        result[0]=alphabet[a];
                        result[1]=alphabet[b];
                        result[2]=alphabet[c];
                        result[3]=alphabet[d];
                        result[4]=alphabet[e];
                        result[5]=alphabet[f];


                        //printf("result : %s\n candidate %x %x %x %x %x",result,candidate.a,candidate.b,candidate.c,candidate.d,candidate.e);

                        // Declarations
                        a=h0;
                        b=h1;
                        c=h2;
                        d=h3;
                        e=h4;
```

Or as you say in your comment, you need to rename your variables to not redefine your loop variables as shown here:

```
for(int a=0; a<26; a++)
{
    for(int b=0; b<26; b++)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<26; c++)
        {
            for(int d=0; d<26; d++)
            {
                for(int e=0; e<26; e++)
                {

                    for(int f=0; f<26; f++)
                    {
                        result[0]=alphabet[a];
                        result[1]=alphabet[b];
                        result[2]=alphabet[c];
                        result[3]=alphabet[d];
                        result[4]=alphabet[e];
                        result[5]=alphabet[f];


                        //printf("result : %s\n candidate %x %x %x %x %x",result,candidate.a,candidate.b,candidate.c,candidate.d,candidate.e);

                        uint32_t A,B,C,D,E,temp; // var "a" is not "A"
                        uint32_t w[80]= {0};


                        // Declarations
                        A=h0;
                        B=h1;
                        C=h2;
                        D=h3;
                        E=h4;
```

Comment: Those `a=h0; `, `b=h1;` etc. assignments that change the loop variables, look fishy to me.

Comment: Thank you. I am working on this since 7 Hours and might have gotten a bit blind. Would have just looked for the error for another hour without seeing it, so thanks for helping me out

Comment: This will compile and might start running (assuming `result`, `alphabet` and `h0` .. `h4` are declared and initialized).  But resetting the loop control variables in the body of the inner loop completely wrecks the controls for the loops.  This is a problem in the original code — but it shouldn't be propagated without at least some commentary.  How many times is the `e` loop going to iterate?  You can't say — but it probably won't be 26 times.  Ditto for the `a` through `d` loops.  For some reason, the code doesn't tamper with `f`; I wonder if that's a bug too?

Comment: Michael, take a look at the SHA1 Pseudo Code. Thats exactly what has to be done, and h0..h4 are constants

Comment: @chenino, well, almost. In the SHA pseudocode they don't tamper with any loop control variables.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got some predicted value to come out, this code generates the correct result. Pls have in mind that this is only a small code excerpt, as the whole code is 418 lines at the moment and will get longer. Task is to do it as fast as possible, including manual loop unrolling and i didnt want to post all of this, as this is too big and the issue was limited to this

Comment: @MichaelWalz My outer loop variables were declared wrong. They shouldnt be tampered within the code, but i was exhausted and by accident declared them two times. i changed the outer loop variables now to k-m and everything works. but this was exactly the issue jonathan discovered and i was looking for

Comment: Get it right, first.  Then measure how fast it is.  Then think about optimizing.  Remember the [Rules of Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization): _"The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." — Michael A. Jackson_

Answer (score 0):

> If i now try to move the uint32_t Declaration line before the first for loop ( but still within the same function, the C compiler warns me the variables are unused and the program crashes as those variables seem to be lost within the loop.

If you put uint32_t a; uint32_t b; ... uint32_t e; outside, and then redeclare as int a; int b; ... int e; , variables declared as uint32_t type are out of scope. Within the most inner for loop, variables a, b, ..., e are those declared in for statement. After all for loops, int a, ..., e are out of scope, and uint32_t variables would be used. But they are not assigned to the desired value.

If you put uint32_t declarations inside the inner for loop, uint32_t 's are in scope, and those int 's are out of scope (or should I say they are "overridden" ?).

> But for performance reasons, i do not want to declare them everytime new.

Let the compiler optimize it if you really want to keep nested loops like now. The variables are not re-declared every time the inner loop is executed. You can compare the result assembly code. Otherwise, consider @JonathanLeffler 's advice, separate them into functions to make your code more readable.

If I made any mistake, please don't hesitate to point it/them out! Thank you!